# How can I understand that sendRawTransaction will generate an error?

Tags: solidity, web3.py, nft

Is there any way using web3py to understand if a transaction generated an error?
I have the below code and I want to know if the token is already minted in order to return an error in API endpoint

```
key = contract.functions.safeMint(tokenId, metadata_uri).buildTransaction({
    'nonce': web3obj.eth.get_transaction_count(current_address),
    'from': current_address,
    'gas': 3000000,
    'value': tokenPrice
    })
try:
    signed_tx = web3obj.eth.account.signTransaction(key, private_key=current_privkey)
    txhash = web3obj.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
    print("txhash:",txhash.hex())
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually detect if transaction is going to fail before sending it by using [estimateGas](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.html?highlight=estimateGas#web3.eth.Eth.estimate_gas) method. Typically this method is supposed to return the gas value that the transaction will need to be executed on the blockchain, if the transaction is going to fail then `estimateGas` will also return a error before the transaction is sent on the blockchain. This is going to save transaction costs for anyone who is interacting with your logic.